# Eclipse highlights my exceptions blue, why?

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Hia.png)

Hello people! My Eclipse highlights my exceptions for no reason, or a reason i don't know of.
I reseted all Preferences, restarted my eclipse. It literally makes my eyes burn while trying to think of how to fix these exceptions.

Thanks a lot in advance <3

Comment: My guess is that your program is outputting an [ANSII escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) sequence that changes the output color.  In fact, it looks like the code is output before the `T` in `Test`.

Comment: If this is an ANSI colour you can turn it off in the Eclipse Preferences in Run/Debug > Console > ANSI Support (Eclipse 2022-09 onwards)